# Infinite conductor plane near a point charge

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

If i have an infinite conductor plane near a point charge ( that is the configuration of the common "Method of images" example), if i calculate the conductor's inducted charged density as

$$\sigma =-\varepsilon _{0}\frac{\partial V}{\partial n}$$

that means that the electric field is only due to the conductor's inducted charged and not also due the point charge. Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean the electric field is only due to the conductor's induced charge. This is so because $V$ in your expression is the *resulting* potential due to the point charge and the induced ones on the plane. This resulting potential gives you information about all charges that produced it. Taking its laplacian on the location of the point charge gives you $\nabla^2V=-4\pi q\delta^3(\vec{r}) /\varepsilon_0$, so it tells you a point charge also produced $V$; and using the condition for the descontinuity of the potential's normal derivative on the condutor's surface gives you the induced surface charge $\sigma$, as in your expression, which is indeed one of the sources of such $V$.

Comment: But dV/dn is the electric field perpendicular to the conductive plane, and this electric field is contemporary due to the point charge and the inducted charges.  For this reason why should't i isolate the induced charge that, in addiction with the point charge, gives the dV/dn mentioned above ? If i use the formula wrote in the post, it seems that all the electric field perpendicular to the conductive plane is generated by the inducted charge...

Comment: Remember where the formula of your post comes from. It actually tells you the *difference* of the potential's normal derivative equals to the surface charge. Therefore, the surface charge is responsible to a *discontinuity* on $E_\bot = -\partial V/\partial n$ instead of being responsible to $E_\bot$ itself.

Comment: What kind of discontinuity ? Isn't dV/dn the conductor's perpendicular Electric field ? So dV/dn is the total electric field since near the conductor it only has the perpendicular component. Where am i wrong ?

Comment: In particular, dV/dn is contemporary due to the induced charge and the point charge. But using the formula of the initial topic is like saying that all the dV/dn is only due to the induced charge

Comment: Imagine there are two regions in your problem. One outside the condutor and another one inside it. The formula in your post comes from the condition $E_\bot^\text{outside}-E_\bot^\text{inside}=\sigma/\varepsilon_o$ evaluated at the interface between the two regions, *i.e.*, at the conductor's surface. Because it is electrostatics, the electric field inside the conductor vanishes, remaining only $E_\bot^\text{outside}= -\partial V/\partial n=\sigma/\varepsilon_o$. Therefore, the *function* $E_\bot$ is discontinuous across the two regions because of the surface charge density.

Comment: But isn't just the external surface to be part of the problem?

Comment: The whole system is part of the problem. But your solution for $V$ by the method of images is valid only outside the conductor. This is not an issue, since $V_\text{inside}$ is a constant that can be determined from the condition for continuity of the potential, $V_\text{outside}=V_\text{inside}$ at the conductor's surface. Therefore you get $E_\bot^\text{inside}=0$ and, consequently, you get the formula in your post.

Comment: The point charge contributes directly to the electric field near the conductor's surface (superposition) ?

Comment: Yes, because there you have the resulting electric field. If not, there would be no *induced* surface charge at all. See it this way: you only have $\sigma$ there because of the presence of the point charge.

Comment: How the tangential component is canceled by the inducted charge ?

Comment: Initially, before electrostatic equilibrium is achieved, tangential components of the field of the point charge on the conductor's surface acts bringing far apart charges of the conductor together to begin to form an induced surface charge on it. Eventually, as such surface charges get closer to one another, their own mutual repulsive field grows enough to cancel the tangent component of the point charge's field. The resulting tangential field then vanishes and remains like that as electrostatic equilibrium have just been achieved.